# Creating Group Constraints in PortfolioAnalytics for R

Tags: r, optimization, finance, r-portfolioanalytics

I am working to put together portfolio optimizations with 11 securities using the PortfolioAnalytics package in R.  Of the 11, 5 are equity funds, 2 are preferred stock funds, 3 are fixed income, and 1 is a money market fund.  I would like to set my asset class allocations to 55% equity, 10% preferred, 30% fixed income, and 5% money market to be fully invested with no leverage and no turnover.  What I would hope to see as the output is the various permutations of portfolios but static asset class allocations.

I have tried to use the add.constraint function to achieve this and I've used the following code:

```
 port <- add.constraint(portfolio = port, type="group",
                        groups= list(c(1:5),(6:7),c(8:10),c(11)),
                        group_min=c(0.55, 0.1, 0.3, 0.05),
                        group_max=c(0.55, 0.1, 0.3, 0.05),
                        group_pos= c(1,1,1,1))
```

When I attempt to generate random portfolios I get the following error message:

```
rportfolios <- random_portfolios(port, permutations = 5000, rp_method = "sample")
Error in rp_transform(w = tmp_group_w, min_sum = cLO[j], max_sum = cUP[j],  : 
  Infeasible portfolio created, perhaps increase max_permutations and/or adjust your parameters.
```

Any thoughts on where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

William, I think the problem is caused by the hard group constraints and the way that the package's random portfolio generator works. Since the portfolios are randomly created it is rare for the generator to produce portfolios that exactly match your criteria given the small number permutations that are tried (i.e. 5000).

This may not be ideal for your problem, but if you provide a little bit of wiggle room in each groups' min-max then the random generator is more likely to create a portfolio that falls within said range. For example instead of setting min=max=0.55, try min=0.5495 and max=0.555 and at the same time increase the permutations to 10k or more. I had the same problem and resolved it this way.